# JS can't delete all images from page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to delete all images from page. The page is in HTML. This is my HTML button:

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Delete Images" onclick="click();" />
```

And the function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function click(){
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].Node.removeChild(images[0]);
    }
  } 
</script>
```

All elements are tagged "img"

Comment: Have you [checked your console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log#t=201610181711498258227) for errors? I can tell you that `Node` is not the name you're looking for and you shouldn't be using `images[0]`. Aaaaaand you're going to have trouble iterating through that array since it's a [live collection.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Comment: Yes Node is not the name you're looking for AND you try to remove images[0] each time so it will not work. You want to remove images[i] ! ;)

Comment: Remove `images[0]` as long as it is truthy. Since `images` is a live list, `images[0]` will change every time you remove one, until there are none  left and it becomes `undefined`.

Comment: `while( images[0] ) images[0].parentNode.removeChild( images[0] );`

Comment: I tried control flow while with images[0], but it doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing a child can only be done from the parent:

```js
function removeImages() {
  var images = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), 0); // get the images as array like object, and turn it into an array using slice

  images.forEach(function(img) { // iterate the images array
    img.parentNode.removeChild(img); // remove the child node via the parent node
  });
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="removeImages()">Remove Images</button>

<div>
  <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/60d837_94f714500a3145a1b98efd7a6fe78ce7~mv2_d_3456_3456_s_4_2.jpg_256" />

  <img src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/442131982/82d94c67fc3d8eb87e07d9bb568c5d4d?v=1" />

  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/625769159339737088/2dwpQAXA.jpg" />

</div>
```

You can also use `img.remove()` instead of the cumbersome `img.parentNode.removeChild(img)`, but it won't work in IE - see [`ChildNode.remove()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).

Comment: `click()` won't be called.

Comment: Yep. You're right. That's really funny. I've fixed it.

Comment: *"...can only be done from the parent"*. Not really true. Modern browsers let you do `node.remove()`. You should explain all the changes you made, and why.

Comment: I've stated `removing a child` for that purpose exactly :) I'll add more info to the code.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have `click` as the function name because `click` is a reserved js method.

For deleting you just need to use `delete()` on that node.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function c(){
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
    }
  } 
</script>
<img  src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/"/>
<img  src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/"/>
<img  src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/"/>
<img  src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/"/>
<img  src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/"/>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Delete Images" onclick="c()"/>
```

Comment: Nice catch of the reserved word click

Comment: Btw - [`node.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Few inputs:

- `click` function will never get fired as it is reserved and take precedence over the `click()` handler attached to `onclick` event. Change the handler name to something meaningful.
- Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to find the `img` elements. It returns a **non-live `NodeList` of all elements descended from the element on which it is invoked that match the specified group of `CSS` selectors.**
- the code `images[i].Node.removeChild(images[0]);` is not correct as `we should remove the element` from the `parentNode`; Indexing was not correct (`images[0]`)

```js
function deleteImages() {

  // query non-live NodeList of all `img` elements
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

  // Loop through each `image` object.
  Object.values(images).forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  });

}
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>My List of ducks</div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Tufted_duck_%28aythya_fuligula%29.JPG/120px-Tufted_duck_%28aythya_fuligula%29.JPG" />
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/Tufted_Duck_pangolakha_Wildlife_Sanctuary_East_Sikkim_India_27.03.2016.jpg/120px-Tufted_Duck_pangolakha_Wildlife_Sanctuary_East_Sikkim_India_27.03.2016.jpg" />
</div>

<div>
  <div>My List of Flowers</div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/Lillium_Stamens.jpg/300px-Lillium_Stamens.jpg" />
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Crateva_religiosa.jpg/220px-Crateva_religiosa.jpg" />
</div>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Delete Images" onclick="deleteImages();" />
```